# How to get xth key of a table in Lua

Tags: lua

I have 2 functions in Lua which create a dictionary table and allow to check if a word exists:

```
local dictTable = {}
local dictTableSize = 0

function buildDictionary()
    local path = system.pathForFile("wordlist.txt")
    local file = io.open( path, "r")
    if file then
        for line in file:lines() do
            dictTable[line] = true
            dictTableSize = dictTableSize + 1
        end      
        io.close(file)
    end
end

function checkWord(word)
    if dictTable[word] then
        return(true)
    else
        return(false)
    end
end
```

Now I want to be able to generate a couple of random words. But since the words are the keys, how can I pick some, given the dictTableSize.

Thanks

Comment: off topic, but your checkWord function could be just one line: `return dictTable[word] == true`

Comment: or `return dictTable[word]`

Comment: i added the comparison to true to avoid returning nils

Comment: just use `not not dictTable[word]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a numerical index for each word to the dictionary while loading it:

```
function buildDictionary()
    local path = system.pathForFile("wordlist.txt")
    local file = io.open( path, "r")
    if file then
        local index = 1
        for line in file:lines() do
            dictTable[line] = true
            dictTable[index] = line
            index = index + 1
        end      
        io.close(file)
    end
end
```

Now you can get a random word like this:

```
function randomWord()
    return dictTable[math.random(1,#dictTable)]
end
```

---

Side note: `nil` evaluates to false in Lua conditionals, so you *could* write `checkWord` like this:

```
function checkWord(word)
    return dictTable[word]
end
```

---

Another side note, you'll get less polution of the global namespace if you wrap the dictionary functionality into an object:

```
local dictionary = { words = {} }

function dictionary:load()
    local path = system.pathForFile('wordlist.txt')
    local file = io.open( path, 'r')
    if file then
        local index = 1
        for line in file:lines() do
            self.words[line] = true
            self.words[index] = line
            index = index + 1
        end      
        io.close(file)
    end
end

function dictionary:checkWord(word)
    return self.words[word]
end

function dictionary:randomWord()
    return self.words[math.random(1,#self.words)]
end
```

Then you can say:

```
dictionary:load()
dictionary:checkWord('foobar')
dictionary:randomWord()
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably two ways: you can keep the *array* with words and just do `words[math.random(#words)]` when you need to pick a random word (just make sure that the second one is different from the first).

The other way is to use `next` the number of times you need:

```
function findNth(t, n)
  local val = next(t)
  for i = 2, n do val = next(t, val) end
  return val
end
```

This will return `b` for `findNth({a = true, b = true, c = true}, 3)` (the order is undefined).

You can avoid repetitive scanning by [memoizing](http://www.lua.org/pil/17.1.html) the results (at this point you will be better off using the first way).

Comment: Thanks however I chose for adding an extra index field as Mud suggested.

Answer (score 0):

this is a trade off that you have for using the word table the way you are. i would invert the word table once you load it, so that you can get references to words by index as well if you have to. something like this:

```
-- mimic your dictionary structure
local t = {
    ["asdf"] = true, ["wer"] = true, ["iweir"] = true, ["erer"] = true
}

-- function to invert your word table
function invert(tbl)
    local t = {}
    for k,_ in pairs(tbl) do
        table.insert(t, k)
    end
    return t
end

-- now the code to grab random words
local idx1, idx2 = math.random(dictTableSize), math.random(dictTableSize)
local new_t = invert(t)
local word1, word2 = new_t[idx1], new_t[idx2]
-- word1 and word2 now have random words from your 'dictTable'
```

Comment: Thank you, however my dictionary contains 230.000 words and it runs on a phone. So inverting the table does not seem to be the most efficient way.